# bcrypt_lib.node: undefined symbol: node_module_register

Tags: linux, node.js, bcrypt

```
 Error: /home/george/Desktop/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: undefined symbol: node_module_register
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings     (/home/george/Desktop/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/george/Desktop/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

What would be the causes for this error ?

- Operating system: Linux Mint 17.1
- gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu
  4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
- Python 2.7.6
- node-gyp@1.0.3
- node 0.12.2

**Where can I find a tutorial about installing bcrypt on linux and the system tools that I need ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `node_module_register` internal API was added to Node.js in v0.11.11 via commit [76b9846](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/76b98462e589a69d9fd48ccb9fb5f6e96b539715).

The `bcrypt` module is a C++ addon, which must be compiled against the same version of Node.js that they are run on.

My best guess is that you've compiled it for use with Node.js v0.12.x but are trying to run it using v0.10.x

Comment: I didn't even compile it because I didn't know that I need to do that. What I need to do in order to compile bcrypt ? I have node v0.12.2 installed.

Comment: Compilation of C++ add-ons occurs during `npm install`. Might you be copying the `node_modules` directory generated by this command to another machine and trying to use it with Node.js v0.10.x?

Comment: Seems that using npm install with node.js v.0.10.33 solves the problem. Thank you sir !