# undefined symbol: node_module_register while using sleep module

Tags: node.js, sleep, node-modules

I am getting the error "undefined symbol: node_module_register" while using "var sleep = require('sleep');"  in my node.js code. I am using following configuration: node version = v6.8.1 npm version = 3.10.9 os = ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bcrypt\_lib.node: undefined symbol: node\_module\_register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495599/bcrypt-lib-node-undefined-symbol-node-module-register)